# Why did my application stop working?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am using VS2008 to create VC++ projects. It was working fine earlier but now when i build any project (old or existing) it is creating an exe but i am not able to run it through IDE or by double clicking it. In debug folder other than exe i can find `.ilk` and `.pdb` files.

There is no error message. When i double click it the application is not opening. I checked the task manager still the application is not listed there.

I kept a break point in

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMFC_DialogDlg, CDialog)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

it is getting hit for couple of times and the debugging stops.

I dont have any problem with C# application. Any help will be appreciated.

**Issue Fixed**

The problem is only restricted to dialog application and after hours of debugging i found out that it is because of `RichEditControl` but i am not sure why. When i remove the rich edit control it works fine.

Comment: What is the error message, after you double clicked the application? $
If there is now error message, then try to start the program from console. There you will probably see some error messages.

What happens if you set a breakpoint just in the first line of your entry point (main)? And start the application in the debugger?.

Comment: "i am not able to run it" -> we need more details on this

Comment: there is no error message. When i double click it the application is not opening. I checked the task manager still the application is not listed there

Comment: what does it do when you run it under the debugger then?

Comment: When i hit F5 it starts and then stops

Comment: When the application starts, then you should be able to set a breakpoint just after your entry point and debug the problem. Or there may be a dll loading issue, but then you should be able to break on the specific exception. Enable all exceptions, set a breakpoint just after entry point and you will see what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. I fixed the issue and updated my question with the resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call [AfxInitRichEdit2()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6hweatz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in your InitInstance() function.